# MongoDB C++ Driver 3.0 get document in string and avoid json

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I am trying to get double type data from the database as the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/cpp/query/) says:

```
auto cursor = db["collection"].find({}, opts);
for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

But I want to avoid converting doc into json because I lost decimal precision. For example:

In database shows this:

```
"lng" : -58.4682568037741
```

But after converting to json, I receive this:

```
"lng" : -58.4682
```

Is there any way to convert it directly to string, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull out the field you want directly as a double.  To print high-precision output, you need to set that on the output stream.  E.g.

```
for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(15)
              << "lng: " << doc["lng"].get_double() << std::endl;
}
```

Gives:

```
lng: -58.4682568037741
```

You may want to verify that `doc["lng"]` is a BSON double before calling `get_double`.

Comment: Is it possible to set the precision somewhere in the mongocxx driver?

Comment: Set the precision for stream output?  No, the driver doesn't control that.